# Correct procedure to cleanup duplicated DEB application

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, 22.04

I have **dbeaver ce 22.1.4** installed in my system (I download a deb package from their site everytime). This is an ubuntu **22.04.1 LTS**, upgraded from 20.04 last week (dbeaver came from 20.04 days).

Today I downloaded the **dbeaver 22.1.5 deb** file and, without thinking too much, I ran `sudo dpkg -i debfile.deb`. I intended to upgrade my application, but now I can open both of them, they're listed in my gnome menu separately. My shortcut launcher icon still points to the older version, and also all shorcuts inside the application are only available to the older version, so I'm thinking they're not reading my user conf files from the same place.

How should I fix that? I would like to have only the most recent version of dbeaver in my system and I would like to keep shortcuts and passwords to all databases. I think I've done this operation about 10 times, for this same app, and the ubuntu upgrade might have changed the way it works somehow.

Comment: No, the "*ubuntu upgrade*" did not change how dpkg works. Have your system list your installed dbeaver packages. They likely have slightly different names.

Comment: running `apt list --installed` i can't find the older version of dbeaver, only the 22.1.5

Comment: Use `whereis` and `which` to show the full path of both executables.

Comment: Thanks! Older version was snap package. I removed it and now I'm importing my settings to the new application